# Who owns a cocoapod's pushing rights?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have this github project I need to put in Trunk, but the email defined in the podspec is not one of the owners of that repository.

Who will be the owner of the pod capable of pushing to it: the owner of the github, the email in the podspec, or the first user pushing it to Trunk from the command line?

Comment: The owner will be the github user account?!?

Comment: I need you to state the same without the ?!? and preferably a link to confirm :D

Comment: The ?!? was because I am confused by the question.  You cannot push to github with authenticating (username/password) and therefore everything written to that account belongs to that account.

Comment: I do not know about the relation between Trunk and the cocoapods, apologies. AFAIK anyone can clone my repository and push to the cocoapod by just modifying the podspec, so I wanted to know who gets the final saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one with an email will be able to push to trunk. Because generally, you can push to trunk from any device as along as you are pushing from the email-account you have registered with.

> https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/getting-setup-with-trunk.html

Comment: So the first email to do it gets ownershi, but someone else can claim it back. Thank you.